# Storing large data in React Component State

Tags: reactjs, performance, state

Can persisting a large array in a React component's state cause a memory leak or performance issues? I am not rendering from the same but need to fetch a large amount of data and process it before rendering children. Since the same data will be used to present results to the user on keypress events and it needs to be fetched over the network, I am persisting it in the state ( changing from an empty array to the populated one).

I am talking of a nested array of about length 1000 and each containing a nested array of about length 10.

Comment: I'm not sure about the storage part of the question, but from experience I have seen that displaying large amounts of rows coming from `state` can bring huge performance issues, as much as completely freezing the page at about 500 rows, so make sure to lazy display the info regardless.

Comment: Yes, I am not rendering a ton of components. Just storing a large array to prevent any more network calls.

Comment: It would be ok to keep your large data in the component state (or even better to keep it in a useRef to avoid rerendering cost) but I suggest using a lazy load to get and process data part by part. do not forget to set a key prop on every record to avoid rerendering. and if you have some children use a memo function.

Comment: So I am using a class component to fetch a large list of options for react-select . Using it in async mode. On user search I tap into this data that I had fetched and filter out the options. I render only 25 options at a time but need to persist the original data for me to construct options from. Since it’s a nested array , I massage it using my custom search criteria before passing the options to render to react-select.

Comment: Should be fine, just use `useRef` or `useMemo` to help prevent performance side effects.